Find the closest previous and next datetime entry in an dateframe index out of datetime entries
I have a df where the index consists of datetime entries and want to find the next and previous entry to a given timestamp (which is in datetime format).
df_temp.index=[2023-05-10 17:00:00, 2023-05-10 18:00:00, 2023-05-10 19:00:00]
timestamp=2023-05-10 17:49:45.551401

Solution should be: [2023-05-10 17:00:00, 2023-05-10 18:00:00]
The whole df consists of timestamp as index and two types of temperature as columns and I want to interpolate the temperature for the given timestamp.
I tried the following to get the previous and next timestamp:
next =df_temp.index[(timestamp-[df_temp.index[df_temp.index > timestamp]])/np.timedelta64(1,'D').TimedeltaIndex()]
prev =df_temp.index[([df_temp.index[df_temp.index < timestamp]]-timestamp)/np.timedelta64(1,'D').TimedeltaIndex()]

and I got the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'list'
Also I have no solution how to interpolate with datetime obj in python.
Thanks for your help!

Why did you think you could subtract a list from a Timestamp?

The problem you're describing and the error don't match, your goal is to sort a pandas dataframe based on datetime values closest to a given datetime.
But the error your getting stuck at is trying to subtract a list from a Timestamp.
next =df_temp.index[(timestamp-[df_temp.index[df_temp.index > timestamp]])/np.timedelta64(1,'D').TimedeltaIndex()]
#                              ^ You're creating a list with one item here
prev =df_temp.index[([df_temp.index[df_temp.index < timestamp]]-timestamp)/np.timedelta64(1,'D').TimedeltaIndex()]
#                    ^ And you're doing it here again, 

If you'll use the actual values for calculation that would maybe get you closer to your goal.
next =df_temp.index[(timestamp-df_temp.index[df_temp.index > timestamp])/np.timedelta64(1,'D').TimedeltaIndex()]

prev =df_temp.index[(df_temp.index[df_temp.index < timestamp]-timestamp)/np.timedelta64(1,'D').TimedeltaIndex()]

and IMO it is considered bad practice to redefine python keywords, like next in this case.

IIUC, use Index.get_indexer in both ffill/bfill modes, then concatenate the arrays and slice the index:
import numpy as np

idx = np.r_[df_temp.index.get_indexer([timestamp], method='ffill'),
            df_temp.index.get_indexer([timestamp], method='bfill')]

out = df_temp.index[idx]

Output:
DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-10 17:00:00', '2023-05-10 18:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

Alternatively:
out = np.r_[df_temp.loc[:timestamp].index[-1:],
            df_temp.loc[timestamp:].index[:1]]

# array(['2023-05-10T17:00:00.000000000', '2023-05-10T18:00:00.000000000'],
#       dtype='datetime64[ns]')

Reproducible input:
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(3)},
                        index=pd.to_datetime(['2023-05-10 17:00:00',
                                              '2023-05-10 18:00:00',
                                              '2023-05-10 19:00:00']))

timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2023-05-10 17:49:45.551401')

